# Passing variables are not decoding

Tags: php, md5

Hey there so I am trying to figure out how to secure variables being passed in the url (I know get is not the most secure, but this is for a test) I am trying to stop the script if the url has been tampered with by checking the id against the md5 hash, but it keeps saying its not working, I have tried a bunch of different variations but keep coming back scratching my head, this is the code I have on the first page that grabs the url input

```
// this goes to main.php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
$variable = $row['case_id'];
$salt = 'foo';
$hash = md5($salt.$variable);
```

This is the code on page two that goes to retrieve the url info

```
// this goes to case.php

$variable = $_REQUEST['case_id'];
$salt = 'foo';
$hash = md5($salt.$variable);
if($hash == $_REQUEST['case_id']){
echo 'success...pass the hash';
}else{
echo 'womp womp';
}
```

This all looks so right yet keep giving me a womp womp, what the heck am I not seeing?

Comment: What's a womp womp and could you translate that into the error you are receiving for us?

Comment: @lxndr, Are you serious ? You really wanna know that ?? ;)

Comment: Well, what are the outputs of both variables?

Comment: What do you think `$_REQUEST['case_id']` is? The value or the hash?

Comment: womp womp is the sound something makes when it fails :) The problem is that when it makes the comparison it skips the echo from the if and goes right to the echo from the else, I assume that if ($hash == $_request['case_id']) keeps coming back as false

Comment: Wouldn't `$_REQUEST['case_id']` be the hashed value?  What point would this code have if it wasn't?  Shouldn't you be getting `$row['case_id']` from the database when you are validating the hash?

Comment: please var_dump both variables and show us.

Comment: @lxndr AKA "sad trombones" I think.  Still not a great error message.

Comment: ack...$_REQUEST['case_id'] is from echo "<a href='case.php?case_id=$row[case_id]'>"; ?>

Comment: The problem is you're using the value of `$_REQUEST['case_id']` to create your hash, plus a salt. `md5('foo'.$_REQUEST['case_id']) != $_REQUEST['case_id']`.

Comment: What is `$_REQUEST['case_id']` ... a clear text GET field or something already hashed? Likewise for the database entry? What are you trying to do here that simply `$variable == $_REQUEST['case_id']` won't tell you (assuming they're both clear text)?

Comment: @SamBrody: So `$_REQUEST['case_id']` is the unhashed variable?  If obviously isn't equal to the hashed version (`$hash`).

Comment: this is the var dump from $hash and $variable from the case.php page string(32) "4718cf785666ea7de07824d6023a772f" string(2) "54"

Comment: @SamBrody, and now you can see that `$hash != $variable`.

Comment: when I try if($hash !== $_REQUEST['case_id']) I get the success method, if my goal is to see if the URL has been tampered with how do I compare variable with hashed version of itself?

Comment: @SamBrody: You need to have *both* the hash **and** the `case_id` in the URL.  Make sure the salt is secret.  That way if the hash matches the data then it's good.  (Or have the hash stored somewhere in the session or something.)  You are comparing the hash to the ***unhashed*** `case_id`, so obviously the are not equal.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Even if I have both the hash and user_if in the url wont they still not match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenarios, like the one you're trying to recreate, assume that the hashed version of a token is stored internally somewhere.  Try storing the hashed version in a session or something.

```
$variable = $row['case_id'];
$salt = 'foo';
$_SESSION['hash'] = md5($salt.$variable);
```

And then...

```
$variable = $_REQUEST['case_id'];
$salt = 'foo';
if ($_SESSION['hash'] == md5($salt.$variable)) {
    echo "Made it!";
}
```

Comment: ok, so step 1 set session with the hash, step 2 pass the hash and case_id through the url, step 3 grab the hash from sessions, step 4 if{ hash from sessions matches hash from url then proceed } else { get an error message} is that more or less correct?

Comment: More or less.  There should be a step between 3 and 4, where you create a hash from the case_id passed through the url, and compare THAT to you the hash stored in a session.

Comment: If you don't want to store the hash comparison in a session, you could also follow Rocket Hasmat's suggestion and put it in the URL.  Each method is equally secure, as long as your salt remains hidden.

Comment: oooooooohhhhhhhhhhh, ok so step 3.5 is grab case_id using $_request, create a hash with that case_id then compare with hash stored in session.....you wouldnt happen to be able to point in the direction that shows me how to set a session when i link is clicked?

Comment: so in the end the problem is that I was comparing the case_id with a hash without first hashing that case_id, so no matter what I was getting a false because case_id on the receiving page was not hashed

Answer (score 0):

use `$_REQUEST['case_id']` for input,output(check)!?  this is false always.

```
$variable = $_REQUEST['case_id'];
$salt = 'foo';
$hash = md5($salt.$variable);
if($hash == $_REQUEST['hash']){
echo 'success...pass the hash';
}else{
echo 'womp womp';
}
```

use java-script for hashing in client side

```
//just include md5.js from the CryptoJS rollups folder
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("foo"+$('#case_id').val());
$('#hash').val(hash);
```

Comment: The point of this is to make sure the URL was not tampered with.  Showing the user the salt makes this completely pointless.